# WKWebView layout issue

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, wkwebview

I am testing a simple app with a ViewController which has a WkWebView. I am just trying to load the google page. As soon as I click on the google search bar, I have several layout errors reported and the whole web page scrolled up as followed :

[image][image]

Since I want the WebView to be full screen, I have added the following contraints on the storyboard to the WebView :

- Align Bottom to : Safe Area (Equals 0)
- Align Top to : Safe Area (Equals 0)
- Trailing Space to: SuperView (Equals 0)
- Leading Space to SuperView (Equals 0)

I have tried to set translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoContraints to false but with no effect.

My error :

2018-08-16 11:38:54.940545+0200 testSignature[93082:2788706] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/testcup_dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D0E3AF7-A79D-4A16-BF2E-D22DD56CBE13/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-08-16 11:38:54.941236+0200 testSignature[93082:2788706] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-08-16 11:38:55.162843+0200 testSignature[93082:2788706] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fd486c45b40 )>",
    "=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fd486f36ff0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fd486f36980 )>",
    "=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fd486f36980 )>",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "UILayoutGuide:0x6040003a0d20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fd486c1d850 )>",
    ""
)

And more ...

My code is simple :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SignViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

    }


    // MARK: WKNavigationDelegate
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("start")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("finish")
    }

}
```

Comment: which swift version do you use

Comment: I am using swift 4.1